# Is there a way to use the cuvid decoder in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, nvidia, codec, cuvid

Wondering if there is way to  use the NVIDIA codecs (e.g. cuvid, scale_npp, nvenc_h264/nvenc_hevc ) in OpenCV ?    These codecs can be used in FFMpeg command line. As  FFMpeg  is a backend for OpenCV (e.g uses libavcodec, libavfilter etc ), is it  possible to specify these codecs in code ?

Comment: I believe this is something that used to work with cuda 7.5 and that hasn't been fixed on opencv with the newer versions of cuda that doesn't used nvcuvid. When it was working you could build with NVCUVID enable and use opencv cudavideoReader. You should ask this question on http://answers.opencv.org/questions/